# Can you configure a merge tool used by Gitlab

Tags: unity-game-engine, merge, yaml, gitlab

We use git and gitlab as our source control tools for our Unity projects. Unity now has a yaml merge tool for merging specific Unity files like scenes, prefabs and assets. We can configure our local files to be merged by this tool. However is it possible to configure gitlab to use this tool on the server side so we can still use merge request by Gitlab?

Comment: Just for clarification: You want GitLab to merge those files with a tool for you? What has this to do with GitLab merge requests?

Comment: When you accept a merge request, the merge is executed by GitLab at server side. For the files mentioned this should be done by Yaml merge which is a tool I only know how to use on my local pc.

Comment: The tool you are describing is something completely different from what a Merge Request is. You could use CI to merge files with your tool and then merge the branch in GitLab.